# PHP echo array in js format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm filling an input type hidden field with an array of values from PHP:

```php
        foreach ($categorie as $cat) {
        $elenco_categorie .= $cat['nome'].", ";
    }
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="elenco_cat" value="'.$elenco_categorie.'">';
```

and after that i am printing the field which will contain the list of all my categories, separated by ", ".
I don't know how to fill a js plugin parameter that requires an array with the values in the input type hidden.
The parameter is like:

```js
{
    categories: [here i need to echo the input type hidden value]
}
```

Comment: do you want the array in javascript or you want to just display it on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()`

```
var categories = $("[name= elenco_cat]").val().split(', ');
```

And in PHP you don't need a loop, just use `implode()`

```
$elenco_categorie = implode(', ', array_column($categorie, 'nome'));
```

This will also prevent the extra `,` at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, last little thing because i'm not practical with js, how can i avoid the final "," that he puts after the splitting? is there a sort of limit?

Comment: If you use `implode()` you won't get the final `,`.

Answer (score 0):

You can push every looped value to a defined variable
The variable  $list will take the new values looped

```
$list = array();

foreach ($categorie as $cat) {
push_array($list,  $cat['nome']);
}
```